# When I close a http server, why do I get a socket hang up?

Tags: http, node.js

I implemented a graceful stop to our node.js server. Basically something like this:

```
var shutDown = function () {
    server.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Server ' + process.pid + ' closed.');

        process.exit();
    });

    console.log('Shutting down ' + process.pid + '...');
    server.close();
}
```

However, when I close the server like this, I get a `Error: socket hang up` error in my continuous requests.

I thought that `server.close()` would make the server stop listening and accepting new requests, but keep processing all pending/open requests. However, that should result in an `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`.

What am I doing wrong?

Additional info: The server consists of a master and three forked children/workers. However, the master is not listening or binding to a port, only the children are, and they are shut down as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_close), it sounds like `server.close()` only stops new connections from coming in, so I'm pretty sure the error is with the already-open connections.

Maybe your `shutDown()` can check [`server.connections`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_connections) and wait until there are no more?

```
var shutDown = function(){
    if(server.connections) return setTimeout(shutDown, 1000);

    // Your shutDown code here
}
```

Slightly uglier (and much less scalable), but without the wait: you can keep track of connections as they occur and close them yourself

```
server.on('connection', function(e){
    // Keep track of e.connection in a list.
    //   You'll want to remove e.connection
    //   from the list if it closes on its own
}

var shutDown = function(){
    // Close all remaining connections in the list

    // Your shutDown code here
}
```

Comment: I actually exactly what you proposed in the first block :)

But when I check for the number of connections first and call `close()` after none are left, there is a chance that it will take a long time until no connections are left.

From the looks at the docs, I thought that after calling `close()`the server would stop listening, I would then wait until all pending requests are processed and only after that I would `exit()`. That's what I'm doing, and that's where the socket hang up occurs.

We must have misinterpreted something.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. See what happens if you do `console.log('Remaining connections: ' + server.connections);` right before and right after `server.close()`, and also `console.log('Remaining connections: ' + this.connections);` right before `process.exit()`. Maybe that will give some useful info.